# Condition Inside string Concatenation VB.NET

Tags: string, vb.net, concatenation

In PHP you can have conditions (if/else) inside a string concatenation.

```
$string= 'X is' . ($x >0 1 ? ' > 10 ': ' < 10 ')';
```

Is this same thing possible in VB.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [string inpterpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) and the [`If`-operator:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx)

```
Dim result = $"X is {If(x > 10, " > 10 ", " <= 10 ")}"
```

Which is syntactic sugar for [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim result = String.Format("X is {0}", If(x > 10, " > 10 ", " <= 10 "))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with string interpolation you can use expressions - [Interpolated Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx)

```
Dim text = $"IsPositive = {If(number > 0, "true", "false")}"
```

> An interpolated string expression creates a string by replacing the
> contained expressions with the ToString **represenations of the
> expressions’ results**

Answer (score 0):

The VB equivalent of the ternary operator is the If operator (as distinct from the If statement).

You can translate your code directly from php to VB:

```
Dim test = "X is" & If(x > 10, " > 10 ", " < 10 ")
```

(I made some corrections for apparent errors in the source, but I'm not familiar with php so I may have inadvertently introduced differences in behavior.)